# How to bring data from SQL database (hosted in Azure) to Xero

Tags: sql-server, xero-api

I am looking to bring data stored in our organization's SQL database (hosted in MS Azure) into Xero (Blue) and eventually to XPM.

I understand that Xero currently supports OAuth2.0 and I am trying to use OAuth2.0 to accomplish this.

I have read through the Developer and API related info on Xero but having issues building this integration.

One key question I have is: does the SQL database (in MS Azure) have a URL which can be used as a redirect URI while authenticating ?

Or should I be looking at getting this data **from SQL database into Xero (Blue) differently?**

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: You need to be more specific and show us what you are trying and what isn't working.

Comment: Hi Rishi, this question is very vague.  It sounds like you need to flesh out the integration at a slightly higher level.  But lets flesh out a few details to point you in the right direction.  First up, it's probably unlikely you'll be integrating SQL directly to Xero's API.  Xero's API is a web based OAuth 2 interface, typically you would have a web/server based middleware layer which connects both to the SQL database and the Xero API, acting as the application layer between them

Comment: Assuming you're in the MS ecosystem, you may want to use the .net SDK to interact with the XeroAPI: https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard

Comment: Thank you @RJaus for your feedback.  Yes, I am trying to integrate a SQL database located in our MS Azure account with Xero so that we can bring in data from SQL into Xero.   I am not sure where to find the URL which I need to provide as the RedirectURI while building the OAuth2.0 integration. From your response it seems like its supposed to be a .net SDK & not a https:// type URL? I will try to attach a couple of images to help demo what I am trying to do as well.

Comment: Hey @Rishi, '.net' is a programming framework, ignore that for now.  The redirectUri is part of the OAuth2 spec, which you can find details of here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow#1-send-a-user-to-authorize-your-app

You set your own redirectUri.  You need to sign up at developer.xero.com & create an App, under which you then set your redirectUri.

Note: The redirectUri will be to your own website/application.  It's where Xero directs the user after they have authorised the api connection.  It is often also referred to as a a callback url.